# Grails Message: No such property: for class: solutions:

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

I implement a java domain class for Grails, just described in Docs here: http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/hibernate.html

```
package foo.bar;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;



@Entity
public class A {

     @Id 
     @GeneratedValue
     private Long id;

     @ElementCollection
     private List<String> buz;


     public Long getId() {
        return id;
     }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


     public void setBuz(List<String> buz) {
         this.buz = buz;
     }

     public List<String> getBuz() {
         return buz;
     }
}
```

And busines code throwing exception:

```
def list = A.findAll()
list.each {
    if (it.buz.contains("foobar")) {
        result = it
}
```

it.buz - throwing exception: Grails Message:

> No such property: buz for class: foo.bar.A Possible solutions: buz.

When I call A.getBuz() directly catch exception:

> Error 2016-07-27 16:51:39,060 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [GET] /
>   No signature of method: static foo.bar.A.getBuz() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
>   Possible solutions: getBuz(), setBuz(java.util.List), getClass().

Can't understand, why Grails search for *static* method getBuz()?
Why invoking by property doesn't work?

Comment: What does your hibernate.cfg.xml look like? Is the class registered with the sessionFactory?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using hibernate class instead of GORM? Did you put this code in java/src? Why you cannot create domain?

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo in:

```
 public List<String> getBuz() {
     returb buz;
 }
```

should be `return buz;`

Comment: Sorry for that - this is just a typo in sample code. The real problem is: _findAll_ method is a standard Groovy method, which injects in every object. In _java.lang.Class_ objects too. Actually, my code A.findAll() looks like: _java.lang.Class<A>.findAll()_ which returns _foo.bar.A_. But _java.lang.Class<A>_ has no method getBuz().